# How do i Get the first and second letter of a username in Django <div> {{Post.author.username.0} } </div>

Tags: django, usernametoken

I want to display images according to the user's first and second letter from the username  instead of an image with rounded corners.
But

```
<div> {{Post.author.username.0} } </div>
```

Returns only the first letter instead.
Please help, how do I return 2 letters for example: Ahmed as  Ah instead of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) to construct a substring with the first two characters:

```
{{ Post.author.username|slice:":2" }}
```